# ListFragment from Support Library does not show @android:id/empty

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-support-library

I have some serious problem getting ListFragment working fully - it does not display empty message

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do I have to set anythind in code? From what I remember ListActivity used it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

It does not display the empty message, or the whole ListView?
Taking a look at the XML declaration I see you are missing the `android:layout_weight="1"` for the ListView.
This is necessary to add, as `android:layout_height="0dip"` will shrink the list to 0, so no data will be visible.